# Is phrase 'But despite' formal enough in a science article

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Can 'But despite' use together at the beginning of a sentence?

> But despite its apparent success, ...

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, of course. Why would you doubt it?

Comment: Some software suggests that it is 'Inappropriate Colloquialisms'.

Comment: Is balabala real?

Comment: yes, it is a real drawback.

Comment: I see you are writing a science paper. I remember the "blahblahblah" parts - they do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the editor but it's probably fine.

A [simple article search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_q=%22But%20despite%22%20&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_occt=any&as_sauthors=&as_publication=&as_ylo=1990&as_yhi=2019&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C11) on Google Scholar yields many results, and a quick skim reveals lots of examples of "but despite" at the beginning of sentences. A [JSTOR search](https://www.jstor.org/action/doAdvancedSearch?c4=AND&c3=AND&f2=all&q4=&q3=&ed=&f3=all&q6=&f6=all&f5=all&q5=&f0=all&q1=&group=none&c5=AND&pt=&q2=&dc.biologicalsciences-discipline=on&f1=all&f4=all&sd=&c2=AND&la=&c6=AND&c1=AND&isbn=&q0=%22but%20despite%22%20&acc=on) for papers in the biological sciences shows similar results. So yes, authors used "but despite" at the start of a sentence and were published.

Some editors may object to the usage for stylistic reasons. For example, "but despite" at the start of the sentence may work just as well with "despite" or "in spite of," without the added *but*. For instance, one could make an argument that *but* in the sentence below is redundant, even if it may form an emphatic purpose. Would you keep *but* in?

> [It](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2871312/) is estimated that 60% of adults with new World Health Organization (WHO) stage IV HIV disease in this setting are now accessing ART [6]. **But despite** this increase in the proportion of eligible patients receiving ART, the absolute number of patients with advanced disease not accessing treatment has remained constant or increased in recent years, due to the evolution of the epidemic [6].

Furthermore, prescriptive training may come into play, as editors recall that *sentences shouldn't start with **but**. They may even make up explanations, like suggesting that a sentence can't start with two conjunctions (even though *despite* is a preposition). And so it goes. I can't predict what an individual editor would do.

Finally, it's important to understand that software programs are fallible in their labels of usage. Some usages may be clearly inappropriate for publication in an academic journal, but many more come down to the purview of individual editors and internal style guides. Furthermore, software developers or algorithms may err on the side of prescriptivism, since it's *hard* to have a comprehensive understanding of how every word or phrase can be used. (See my phone's tendency to incorrectly autocorrect "its" to "it's.") So if another phrase is marked and you're unsure of it, do more research. If there isn't a volume of research from people saying, "No, don't ever do that thing!" and if the occurrence exists in the wild, it's likely fine.

Comment: "They may even make up explanations, like suggesting that a sentence can't start with two conjunctions." [Despite](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/despite-is-not-a-conjunction/) is not a conjunction.

Comment: @PhilSweet *I jumped for joy. Despite* ***that***, *I was sad afterwards.* Here, to use the terminology in that link, *despite* governs the pronoun *that* which stands in place of a previous *verbal clause*. It's not governing a noun or a noun phrase. (But I may agree that it doesn't act as a normal conjunction.)

Comment: @Phil Sweet Agreed! I have however actually heard that explanation.

Comment: "Despite" is a preposition. "But" is the coordinator, so it's not a case of two coordinators.

Comment: @BillJ Exactly. It's an illogical explanation. I'll update the answer to make that clear.